# C++ Input validation to make sure a number was entered instead of a letter

Tags: c++, validation, while-loop

So I'm trying to set this program up to calculate the balance of an account.  I need to make sure the starting balance is entered as a positive number.  I have the positive part down, but how do I make sure that the input is also a number and not letters or other non-numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

double  startBal,    // Starting balance of the savings account
        ratePercent, // Annual percentage interest rate on account
        rateAnnual,  // Annual decimal interest rate on account
        rateMonth,   // Monthly decimal interest rate on account
        deposit1,    // First month's deposits
        deposit2,    // Second month's deposits
        deposit3,    // Third month's deposits
        interest1,   // Interest earned after first month
        interest2,   // Interest earned after second month
        interest3,   // Interest earned after third month
        count;       // Count the iterations

// Get the starting balance for the account.
cout << "What is the starting balance of the account?" << endl;
cin >> startBal;
while (startBal < 0 ) {
    cout << "Input must be a positive number. Please enter a valid number." << endl;
    cin >> startBal;
}

// Get the annual percentage rate.
cout << "What is the annual interest rate in percentage form?" << endl;
cin >> ratePercent;

// Calculate the annual decimal rate for the account.
rateAnnual = ratePercent / 100;

// Calculate the monthly decimal rate for the account.
rateMonth = rateAnnual / 12;

while (count = 1; count <= 3; count++)
{

}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: `while (count = 1; count <= 3; count++)` ? Huh ?

Comment: This user needs to learn arrays.

Comment: I'm on chapter 5.  Arrays are chapter 8 ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can verify if `cin` was successful:

```
double startBal;
while (!(std::cin >> startBal)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Enter a valid number\n";
}

std::cout << startBal << endl;
```

Don't forget to `#include <limits>` to use `std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`.

Comment: Should probably replace `10000` with `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`

Comment: Verifying that the input was successful is not quite the same thing as verifying that the user entered a number. If the user entered 123xyz for instance the input would be successful (reading 123) but 123xyz is not a number.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's just Visual Studio, but I never have to `#include <limits>` nor prefix `std::`.

Comment: If you declare `using namespace std;` you don't need to prefix with `std::`

Comment: @john That is complicated, because you would to have to define what is considered a number. `123 xyz` is a number? And `123\nxyz`? If he has a more detailed definition on what he consider a valid number we can give a more precise answer.

Comment: @MuriloVasconcelos I agree, and the OP probably hasn't thought that through. But I remember I once gave an answer like yours only for the OP to say in a comment 'but it doesn't work when I enter 12ab'.

Comment: @john I see. The thing is, to give him a complete answer I would have to talk about capture the input as string and build a DFA to accept a double or suggest him to use a regex library. But maybe this answer fits his needs, since it looks like his program is not that complex.

Answer (score 1):

```
double x;
std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
std::cin >> x;
while(std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cout << "Bad entry.  Enter a NUMBER: ";
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

Replace `x` and `double` with whatever variable name and type you need.  And obviously, modify your prompts to whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is actually quite difficult. The only completely correct way is to read your input as a string, then see if the string is in the right format for a number, and only then convert the string to a number. I think that's quite difficult when you're just a beginner.